# MATLAB Inner matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, syntax-error

I have `t=linspace(1, 10, 91)`

I have to define with those values the function `y=(((e^(t/10))sin(t))/((t^2)+1)`

I write this in MATLAB:

```
y=((exp(t/10)*sin(t))/((t.^2)+1)
```

Matlab says:

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

I then tried to fix it whatever way possible and put a period  before `*` and this is what I got:

```
y=((exp(t/10).*sin(t))/((t.^2)+1))

y =
    0.0077
```

I think this isn't the answer because it is not giving me the answer for each value of the matrix. I really don't know what happened.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Your missing the dot before `/`:

```
y=((exp(t/10).*sin(t)) ./ ((t.^2)+1))
```

Note: You can easily find problems like this on your own. You could have done

```
((exp(t/10).*sin(t))
```

and seen that it works as expected. Then you could try `((t.^2)+1))`. Wow, that works as well. Thus, the problem has to be cause by the `/`. From there to `./` it is just a small step.

Comment: Your welcome, even if that answer was not very guru-qualifying ;). If your problem is solved, you can always mark the correct by clicking on the checkmark next to the correct answer. This way everybody else sees what helped you and nobody has to provide further answers. See [about].